# How to use button or hyperlink to invoke a image stored in Database

Tags: c#, jquery

I have one grid view control in my application in which I want to have a button or hyperlink to show stored image (stored as "image" datatype in my table).

Is there anyone who can help me in this?   Any Jquery Examples?

Comment: Welcome to SO,please show your code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your database has an http API (like CouchDB for example) and is exposed on the Internet (as opposed to behind a firewall), there is no way for a browser to access the image data stored in your database.

The first thing you have to do is to write code in the back-end to make the image data accessible via http or https. There are many ways how to do this, depending on the database and server framework you are using.

Only after this is done, you can create an `<img>` element using javascript on your web page and set its `src` attribute to the URL of the image. The URL is defined by a) where your server is running (that is the host part) and b) at what path your back-end code is serving the image data. (that's often called the *route*).

The URL consists of these parts:

`<http or https>://<your domain or the servers's IP address (the host)><route (starting with /)>`

Once you know the URL, this is how you can create the `<img>` element using jquery and add it as a child of another element (in this example the parent has id='parent')

```
$("#parent").append("<img src="http://...">")
```